# Why the widget btn1 in the subpage of QStackedWidget can only define signals for QStackedWidget, but not for page: deviceTypeSelect in QStackedWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, qstackedwidget

I want to use btn1 to send a signal to the slot function of deviceTypeSelect, but btn1 can only be associated with QStackedWidget.
[image]

[image]

Comment: what *slot function*?

Comment: The custom slot method in deviceTypeSelect, I will promote deviceTypeSelect.

Comment: You are going to do it but you haven't, that's why you can't find that slot in Qt Designer. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Only the predefined slots of *existing* classes can be used. Qt Designer cannot know what slots are going to be in a widget that **will** be promoted, how could it?!

Comment: I did promoted and the result is still the same.This demo is not easy to describe with code, but pictures are better.

Comment: @Alex: the slots are defined in the python class that is going to be used as the promoted widget, right?

Comment: The key is why the subpage of QStackedWidget can't accept signal?

Comment: @musicamante yeah, That's it what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems.

The first is conceptual: Designer cannot know *anything* about custom slots that are going to be implemented in a promoted widget, and it even should *not*. The connection to those slots can only be achieved programmatically, and that's for good reasons: Designer cannot "inspect" (nor it should) the source of the files that *will* be promoted, and it's also completely possible that one would promote a widget and use different classes with the same design files.

The other problem is technical: the "pages" of multipage widgets like QStackedWidget or QTabWidget cannot be used as signal targets on Designer. I don't know if it's just a missing feature or it's by design (knowing how multipage widget plugins are dealt with I wouldn't bet about the it), but unfortunately it really is not possible.
If you want to connect to standard QWidget slots (`setEnabled()` etc.), set a dummy boxed layout on the page, and add another QWidget in it, but if you use custom slots, as explained before, those *must* be manually connected from your code.

Comment: Thanks for comment ,So I can only promote QStackedWidget, and then customize the slot in it to associate the signal of btn1.

Comment: That's up to you, but since custom slots can only be connected programmatically there's no much difference, it just depends on what that slot is going to do: if it does something on *that page* only, promoting the page will suffice, but if its interaction is in the common scope of the stacked widget, promote that one instead.